# Add value to cell in a loop

Tags: matlab

I have simple code as below and try to insert the values into cell array.

```
a = cell(14,1);
for i = 1:14
    a(i:1)=sin(i)
end
```

However error came out as:

```
Conversion to cell from double is not possible.
```

What is the problem for this code?

Comment: try `a{i}=sin(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either expand the cell, or wrap the result of the sin function in a cell.

```
a = cell(14,1);
b = cell(14,1);

for ii = 1:14
    a{ii} = sin(ii);
    b(ii) = {sin(ii)};
end

isequal(a,b)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is wrong. `a(i:1)` can not work inside a loop over i. Simply using `a(i)` will give you the desired result.